# How do I find implementations of a function type?

Tags: go

In Go, it's possible to create function types (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) like this

```
type Printer func(s string)
```

How can I find all of the functions which satisfy this type? For example, if I had the file below, how could I find out that `consolePrinter` is a `Printer`?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    printToScreen(consolePrinter)
}

// Printer defines a function that prints a string.
type Printer func(s string)

func printToScreen(p Printer) {
    p("Hello")
}

// consolePrinter is a Printer (the function signature is identical).
func consolePrinter(s string) {
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

I tried out guru, but the `implements` feature doesn't seem to support function types.

```
guru implements ./main.go:#134
/Users/adrian/go/gurutest/main.go:10.6-10.12: signature type Printer implements only interface{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for functions that are [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to `Printer`.

The `guru` tool does not support an "assignable to" query.

You can write a program to find functions that are assignable to `Printer` using the [go/types](https://godoc.org/go/types) package.  Follow the [tutorial](https://github.com/golang/example/tree/master/gotypes) to type check code and use [AssignableTo](https://godoc.org/go/types#AssignableTo) to find the functions.

If you are only interested in finding functions declared at package level in gofmted code, then searching your code with a regexp might be good enough. This approach is not accurate, but is simple to do in many editors or the command line.

Comment: I've submitted a change to `guru` (https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/tools/+/114800) which provides the required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here `consolePrinter` is not of type `Printer` it is required to declare `consolePrinter` to be of type `Printer`.You see `console.Printer` is a function with same underlying type that's why it can be pass to `printToScreen` which takes `Printer type`. Have a Look at the difference with their types

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    printToScreen(consolePrinter)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(consolePrinter)) // Prints func(string) as its type
}

// Printer defines a function that prints a string.
type Printer func(s string)

func printToScreen(p Printer) {
    var consoleprint Printer // declare to be of type Printer
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(consoleprint)) // Prints main.Printer
    p("Hello")
}

// consolePrinter is a Printer (the function signature is identical).
func consolePrinter(s string) {
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/PCMqMv7Z1Za)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to get across here. The code just seems to define a variable as a Printer, then print its type? It doesn't appear to help find functions which have the same signature as Printer defines.

Comment: I have told you the reason why `consolePrinter` is not of type `Printer` even if they have same signature. Also for implementing a type use an interface with same matching function which is implemented on another function

Answer (score 0):

Working example, based on Thundercat's answer. `guru` would need to do something like this to provide support for looking up suitable functions to pass in (e.g. implementations of `http.HandleFunc`).

```
 package main

 import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/importer"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "go/types"
    "log"
 )

 const hello = `package main

 import "fmt"

 const x = 1;

 func main() {
         fmt.Println("Hello, world")
 }

 // Printer defines a function that prints a string.
 type Printer func(s string)

 func consolePrinter(s string) {
    fmt.Println(s)
 }
 `

 func main() {
    fset := token.NewFileSet()

    // Parse the input string, []byte, or io.Reader,
    // recording position information in fset.
    // ParseFile returns an *ast.File, a syntax tree.
    f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "hello.go", hello, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // parse error
    }

    // A Config controls various options of the type checker.
    // The defaults work fine except for one setting:
    // we must specify how to deal with imports.
    conf := types.Config{Importer: importer.Default()}

    // Type-check the package containing only file f.
    // Check returns a *types.Package.
    pkg, err := conf.Check("cmd/hello", fset, []*ast.File{f}, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // type error
    }

    names, signatures := getFunctionTypes(pkg)
    for i, name := range names {
        fmt.Println("Functions which implement", name)
        for _, implementor := range getFunctionsWhichImplement(signatures[i], pkg) {
            fmt.Println(implementor)
        }
    }
 }

 func getFunctionTypes(pkg *types.Package) (names []string, signatures []*types.Signature) {
    for _, name := range pkg.Scope().Names() {
        o := pkg.Scope().Lookup(name)

        if _, isType := o.(*types.TypeName); !isType {
            continue
        }
        var sig *types.Signature
        var isFunc bool
        if sig, isFunc = o.Type().Underlying().(*types.Signature); !isFunc {
            continue
        }
        signatures = append(signatures, sig)
        names = append(names, name)
    }
    return
 }

 func getFunctionsWhichImplement(sig *types.Signature, pkg *types.Package) (fns []types.Object) {
    for _, name := range pkg.Scope().Names() {
        o := pkg.Scope().Lookup(name)
        if _, isType := o.(*types.TypeName); isType {
            continue
        }
        var csig *types.Signature
        var isFunc bool
        if csig, isFunc = o.Type().Underlying().(*types.Signature); !isFunc {
            continue
        }

        if types.AssignableTo(sig, csig) {
            fns = append(fns, o)
        }
    }
    return
 }
```

The output of this code is shown below:

```
 Functions which implement Printer
 func cmd/hello.consolePrinter(s string)
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm sure there are better ways for the specific case of printing, but in general you may be better to take a more idiomatic go approach of using interfaces.

Declare an interface and types that implement the interface:

```
type StringPrinter interface {
    PrintString(string)
}

type Console struct {
    // console specific stuff
}

func (c *Console) PrintString(s string) {
    // Printing code
}

type Paper struct {
    // paper specific stuff
}

func (p *Paper) PrintString(s string) {
    // Printing code
}
```

Then to print in different ways you can access through an interface in a generic way:

```
func main() {
    var sp StringPrinter

    sp = &Console{ /* member inits */ }
    sp.PrintString("Hello on console") 

    sp = &Paper{ /* member inits */ }
    sp.PrintString("Hello on paper")
}
```

You will be able to use guru on this form of code to find objects that implement the StringPrinter interface.